# GeoDataClient. Autocompelete Prediction Task Cancellation

Tags: android, google-places-api

Is there any way to cancel the latest autocomplete prediction task in order to save usage limit.

For example, each time I quickly type text or delete symbol new task is created. Half second- second later I receive all result asynchronously.

All I need is to save the last input task and cancel it before the new task with a new query is created.

So could you make `getAutocompletePredictions(...)` task cancellable or is there already exist any way to cancel exactly this task?

Please, do not suggest any delay inputs, handlers, and timers.

All I manage to do so far is cancel only DISPLAY Result:

```
override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        cancellationSource?.cancel()
        cancellationSource = CancellationTokenSource()
        val cancelableAutocompleteListTask = TaskCompletionSource<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse>(cancellationSource!!.token)
        geoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(s?.toString(), null, autocompleteFilter)
                .addOnCompleteListener { response ->
                    if (response.isSuccessful) cancelableAutocompleteListTask.trySetResult(response.result)
                    response.exception?.let { cancelableAutocompleteListTask.setException(it) }
                }
        cancelableAutocompleteListTask.task
                .addOnCompleteListener { response ->
                    if (response.isCanceled) return@addOnCompleteListener
                    if (response.isSuccessful && response.result != null) {
                        val filteredResults = response.result?.map {
                            "PLACE name = ${it.getFullText(null)}, it.placeTypes = ${it.placeTypes?.joinToString()}".log
                            it
                        }?.filter { it.isDataValid }
                        placeAutocompleteAdapter.setNewData(filteredResults)
                        c_recognize_address_autocomplete.visibility = if (filteredResults?.isEmpty() == false) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
                    } else {
                        c_recognize_address_autocomplete.visibility = View.GONE
                        "error = ${response.exception}".toastView
                    }
                }
    }
```

So, though I could cancel `cancelableAutocompleteListTask` using cancellationSource.token I still receive all result from `geoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(...)`, which decrease usage quota.

Thank for you understanding. Hope for quick answer.